# Conditions for a function f: R-->R (Reals) to have an antiderivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Ok, so I gather if a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $  is to have an antiderivative.

The first/obvious guess is to use F(x) with :

$$F(x):= \int_a^x f(t)dt +C; C $$ a Real constant.

Then the FTC grants us : 
     $$ F'(x)=f(x) $$

Now, the details:
  1) I believe f(x) must be continuous at $x$ in order to have $F'(x)=f(x)$, right?

2)Must the (Riemann) integral converge for the identity to apply?
  If so, then f must be a.e. continuous and bounded.

3)Curious: Since F is differentiable, it is continuous. So we then
   need F to be continuous on x (t is just a dummy variable, so it won't matter). For this last it seems boundedness of $f$ is enough, in that
  $F(x+h)-F(x):= \int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt$ can be made small-enough by making
  $h$ small-enough (right?) giving us a $\delta - \epsilon$ argument for the
  continuity of $F$ at $x$
  Can this be extended to $\mathbb R^n$? I am thinking of conservative
  vector fields and the condition $U_x= V_y$ for $n=2$ but I can't see
  for $n>2$. 
   Is this  right?
    TIA.
  EDIT: I am trying to determine the most general conditions under which
 $F'=f$
   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Wrong. *If* $f$ is continuous, then $F'=f$. But in some cases, you still have $F'=f$ even if $f$ is discontinuous.
2. There are no convergence questions here. In order that this makes sense, $f$ must be Riemann-integrable. And then $\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ exists automatically.

Comment: Thanks. For #2, for the expression to make sense, then we need f to be a,e, continuous and bounded for F to make sense, right?

Comment: For the expression to make sense with respect to which integral?

Comment: In general. Doesn't $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ have to converge, i.e., the integral has to exist? Do you have examples of 1)?EDIT: I am trying to determine the most general conditions under which F is an antiderivative for f.

Comment: We are not talking about improper integrals here and therefore there are no convergence issues.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am misusing the term 'Convergence', sorry for confusion. Do we need to have f a.e. continuous and bounded (so that the integral exists)? If so, is this sufficient to have F'=f ?

Comment: The answer depends upon which integral you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For the Riemann integral of $f$ to exist on a interval, you need that the set of discontinuity points of $f$ has zero Lebesgue measure. In particular, if the set of discontinuity points of $f$ is countable (or finite, of course), then the Riemann integral of $f$ exists.

In the above situation, i.e. when $f$ is Riemann-integrable on an interval $[a,b]$, then $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ exists and $F'(x)=f(x)$ at all points of continuity of $f$. Where $f$ is not continuous, you can have things like this: let $f=1_{[1,2]}$, that is $f(x)=1$ on $[1,2]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then, as $f$ has a jump at $1$, it cannot be the derivative of a function on intervals $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ (because it fails [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))).

Comment: Thank you. Can we then find an antiderivative of every function with the Darboux property ( By using the Lebesgue integral)? How does R-integrability relate to the Darboux property, i.e., does one imply the other? It seems clear every R-integrable function satisfies Darboux, right?

Comment: No, it's not enough. A function could have the Darboux property and still be very discontinuous. I copy from [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/CC224B9D70EB9D8729096B730DEDDDC3/S0008439559051141a.pdf/discontinuous_functions_with_the_darboux_property.pdf): "Darboux*s function is Riemann-integrable but later Volterra gave a derivative function which is not Riemann-integrable. Then Lebesgue gave a function with the Darboux property which is not a derivative function, and is discontinuous for all $x$ . *(continued)*

Comment: "*More recently, the writer constructed
functions f(x) which have the Darboux property but which are not
Lebesgue measurable on any interval, and for which the equation $f(x)=u$ has, for every real $u$, a continuum number of solutions in every interval".*